# SQL Job saying it executed but not showing up in Windows Event Viewer

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, ssis, windows-server-2003

I have an 2005 SSIS package that runs on a Windows 2003 Server hitting a SQL Server 2005 database on the same server.  I have a package that SQL Server Job Scheduler reports executing successfully, yet on certain days the functionality in side the package does not run.  Desperate for answers, I have been searching the application's audit logs and Windows Event Viewer.  I noticed that days this package does not execute coincide s with days that another package stops (does not fail how you would typically expect a package to fail) due to high memory usage.  The other thing I noticed by searching through the Windows Event Viewer is that even though SQL Server Job Scheduler claims to of executed the package successfully, there is no record of the event in the Event Viewer.

After all of that, my question is: are there any reports of bugs with the SQL Server / Windows Server combination regarding executing packages after high server memory usage in the same day?   Regardless of the first, any suggestions on a work around?

Other related facts: due to other projects in the works, I am not authorized to modify the packages that fails when the memory usage is high.. I'm only allowed to restart the package.

Please let me know if I need to provide additional details.

Additional Details 2012.01.30
Recently an 8 GB stick of memory was removed from the server.  SQL Server's max allocation was set to 30 GB.  Once the stick was removed, only 24 GB remained.

2012.02.10:  I was given the approval to rewrite the memory leaking package.

Comment: What logging is turned on with the package? Assuming your logging is not turned on, would you have the ability to run a program like (DTLoggedExec)[http://dtloggedexec.codeplex.com/] to capture what's really going on with your package in these situations? Does the SQL Agent job step log output and/or include the step output in history?

Comment: The package has SSIS log provider for Windows Event Log enabled on the package.  When I looked at the sysdtslog90 and windows event viewer, I do not find any any record of the package executing.  Also, the package has an on error event that fires an email when the package fails.  I do not have the ability to run any 3rd party software.  I'm requesting access to the server to further investigate the SQL Agent log.

Comment: Those two items +  writing to an audit log are the only forms of logging I'm familiar with.  The 3rd party software review process process at my company takes months to complete.  Is there any other form of logging built into BIDS that I can add to my package?  Modifications like that are possible for this given situation.

Comment: How familiar are you with details of the job and package? Is it possible that one of them have conditional logic that prevents / stops package execution?

Comment: The package consists of several Execute SQL tasks consolidating data into one table.  After consolidation, a foreach loop executes ~150 "rules" (Ex: `update Table set Product = rtrim(ltrim(replace(Product, '>', ''))) where Product like '%>%'` ).  The package before, during, or after different rules.  On a different note, you should check edit to the original post regarding SQL Server / Server memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I determined that the execution of the previously mention rules in a foreach loop caused the memory leak on the server.  I removed this looping package and replaced it with a stored procedure.

Since this change went into effect, no out of memory exceptions have occurred in the problem package and my package is running successfully.